# how to find angle between two latitudes and logtitudes and display them on circle?

Tags: java, android, geometry

Hey I have circle as below.
Circle has two points A(latitude1,longitude1) and B(latitude2, longitude2).
and two (latitude, longitude) pairs. Among them one is (Say A) is the center point of the circle. Now I want to put another point on the circle (B) by calculating angle. 
Please how can I do this in android canvas?
Right now to get angle I am using following function:

```
public double getAngle(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2)
{
    double dx = lat2 - lat1;
    // Minus to correct for coord re-mapping
    double dy =  Math.cos(Math.PI/180*lat1)*(lon2 - lon1);

    double inRads = Math.atan2(dy,dx);

    if (inRads < 0)
        inRads = Math.abs(inRads);
    else
        inRads = 2*Math.PI - inRads;

    return inRads;
}
```

Is above function is correct to get angle? and if yes then now how can I display that point on canvas?

Comment: Thanks ya after changing dy to lon2 -lon1 I get inRads and using that I draw that point on circle with  canvas.drawBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),imageNames[0]), (float)(center + r * Math.cos(angle)), (float)(center + r * Math.sin(angle)), null);
Is that correct?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That `Math.cos()` is awfully suspicious. Why isn't `dy` simply `lon2 - lon1`? Once you have inRads, why are you fiddling with it? `Math.atan2()` returns a correct angle between -Pi and +Pi.

Comment: don't confuse mathe angles with geo, have you ever looked at a compass? geo: 0-360, 0 = north, clockwise raising. mathe: -pi, pi, 0 = east, counterclockwise(!) rasing

Comment: the  cos() is not always suspicious, it is always used in geography to correct the fact that the distance between two longitudes shrinks the more north you go, by a factor of cos(latitude)